# Background-image not working on iPhone/iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, background-image

Hello I have a problem with my `background-image` on Apple devices (iPhone/iPad) 
My background looks like I want in all the browsers and on Android devices just not on Apple devices

like this in browsers: Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, IE

[image: Firefox,Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge, IE]

like this on Android

[image: Samsung, LG, Sony]

and like this on Apple devices

[image: iPhone, iPad]

for the HTML it is only a normal `<div class="hero"> </div>`

this is my CSS (sass)

```
.hero
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    position: relative
    background:
        image: url(../image/pics/thailand.jpg)
        position: center
        size: cover
        attachment: fixed
```

[This is the page](http://danyweis.com)

I tried already some solutions from "Questions that may already have my answer" but nothing worked for me

Thank you for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot solutions and I did not want to use JS so for some reason the property attachment fixed does not work correctly on IOS so I did this for media and now the picture look good it is just not fixed anymore

```
 @media screen and(max-width:800px)
    .hero
        background:
            attachment: scroll
```

If somebody brings me an other solution that would make me happy

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Stellar.Js with the following setup...

HTML (Attach to related div)

```
data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"
```

CSS

```
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

JS

```
$(window).stellar({ horizontalScrolling: false, responsive: true });
```

& If you have any blank spaces or alignment issues try

```
$(window).stellar({ horizontalScrolling: false, responsive: true, verticalOffset: 50 });
```

Hope this helps!